# running the object_detection_model of tensorflow ( error by downloading the model)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I use Windows 10 and I want to use tensorflow for object detection. I have a problem with running the Tensorflow object_detection_tutorial in jupyter Notebook. I installed all the necessary packages and I did the Portbuf compilation with version 3.4. I get a trouble by Download Model:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-afc84e8d6c88>", line 6
    file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
            ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

[image: see the image]

Comment: You need to add indentation to your loop. `file_name = os ...` should start on a deeper indentation level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Problem is solved now. What I did is to download the neuronal network model, extract it and add a local path (without url address). It was an Proxy-Problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKhSW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E8uD.png)